# Run the .Net installer from custom action within Wix Installer?

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer

I currently have a wix installer which produces a single MSI. As part of this I check whether or not the correct version of the .Net runtime is installed on the machine. If not it currently aborts the installation and prompts the user to install it.
I initially tried using a different method as per this:

https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_dotnet.html

But this produces an exe and I need it to remain as a single MSI.

Would it be possible to instead have a custom action that runs the .Net offline installer and install it then continue with the MSI installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this isn't possible. MSI has a mutex that prevents two MSIs from running at the same time. (There is a slight exception to this rule but it rules out any hope of having a proper silent installation.)

You can use WiX Burn to create a setup.exe that installs .NET and then your MSI.

Or your application could switch to .NET Core and bundle it's own .NET inside the MSI without installing a system wide instance.

Comment: Adding this short explanation about [MSI mutex](https://serverfault.com/a/274675/20599). Most of the time packages full of common runtimes are frowned upon in corporate environments - it is just a lot of work to remove them. For home users the .NET framework is usually installed via Windows Update - at least in "some version".

Comment: Corp environments (which I work in a very large one) like to have packages split out so they can be normalized and chained together.  Basically, for most run of the mill apps, you don't need a bootstrapper because they do that.

Comment: Agree. One thing I would like to add is that "unusual runtimes" - as in runtimes that are not widely distributed - should be include in your **`setup.exe`** bundle or otherwise safely preserved and available online (prefer to include in bundle). However, the normal ones - such as **`.NET`** and **`VSC++ Runtime`** - I would download on **`setup.exe`** launch. What you bundle will almost always be outdated by the time it is run and can constitute a security risk - of caliber even.